# javascript css change overiding css

Tags: javascript, css, hover

Sorry for the unclear question title...couldn't think how to put the question in a shirt summary.

I have css to change the background-color of a link when hovered over (with css transistion to fade the color in).

Due the nature of the requirement, I use JS to change the background color of the link which is in use (I have tabs, the selected one's background is selected using JS - getElementById('foo').style.backgroundColor = 'red';).

Even after a tab has been selected, I want the others to change color when hovering.

It works initially but once I have clicked on a tab (JS then changes that tab's color), the hover css style does not work - the other links no longer change color when hovering.

Has anyone else had the same problem?

HTML:

```
<div class="software_section_selects_wrapper">
    <a id="a1" onclick="displayArrow('1')">OVERVIEW</a>
    <a id="a2" onclick="displayArrow('2')">SPECS</a>
    <a id="a3" onclick="displayArrow('3')">COMMENTS</a>
    <div style="clear: both;"></div>
</div>

<div class="section_selects_arrow_wrapper">
    <img id="red1"alt="" src="images/red_arrow.png" width="40px" height="20px"/>
    <img id="red2"alt="" src="images/red_arrow.png" width="40px" height="20px"/>
    <img id="red3"alt="" src="images/red_arrow.png" width="40px" height="20px"/>
</div>

<div id="overview" class="software_overview">

</div>
<div id="specs" class="software_overview">

</div>
<div id="comments" class="software_overview">


</div>
```

JS:

```
    function displayArrow(arrow) {
     var which_arrow = arrow;

     if (which_arrow == '1') {
         document.getElementById('a1').style.backgroundColor = 'red';
         document.getElementById('a2').style.backgroundColor = 'black';
         document.getElementById('a3').style.backgroundColor = 'black';

         document.getElementById('red1').style.display = 'block';
         document.getElementById('red2').style.display = 'none';
         document.getElementById('red3').style.display = 'none';

         document.getElementById('overview').style.display = 'block';
         document.getElementById('specs').style.display = 'none';
         document.getElementById('comments').style.display = 'none';
     } else if (which_arrow == '2') {
         document.getElementById('a2').style.backgroundColor = 'red';
         document.getElementById('a1').style.backgroundColor = 'black';
         document.getElementById('a3').style.backgroundColor = 'black';

         document.getElementById('red2').style.display = 'block';
         document.getElementById('red1').style.display = 'none';
         document.getElementById('red3').style.display = 'none';

         document.getElementById('specs').style.display = 'block';
         document.getElementById('overview').style.display = 'none';
         document.getElementById('comments').style.display = 'none';
     } else {
         document.getElementById('a3').style.backgroundColor = 'red';
         document.getElementById('a2').style.backgroundColor = 'black';
         document.getElementById('a1').style.backgroundColor = 'black';

         document.getElementById('red3').style.display = 'block';
         document.getElementById('red1').style.display = 'none';
         document.getElementById('red2').style.display = 'none';

         document.getElementById('comments').style.display = 'block';
         document.getElementById('overview').style.display = 'none';
         document.getElementById('specs').style.display = 'none';
     }
 }
```

Comment: post your code instead

Comment: Please provide the css and Javascript

Answer (score 0):

This line of code:

```
document.getElementById('a2').style.backgroundColor = 'black';
```

adds an inline style which is stronger than `:hover` styling coming from the stylesheet.

Instead of adding the inline style, reset it to nothing:

```
document.getElementById('a2').style.backgroundColor = '';
```

Answer (score 0):

I think his is what you are looking for

```
<div class="software_section_selects_wrapper">
            <a id="a1" onclick="displayArrow('1')" onmouseover="MouseHoverMethod(this)" onmouseout="MouseOutMethod(this)">OVERVIEW</a>
            <a id="a2" onclick="displayArrow('2')" onmouseover="MouseHoverMethod(this)" onmouseout="MouseOutMethod(this)">SPECS</a>
            <a id="a3" onclick="displayArrow('3')" onmouseover="MouseHoverMethod(this)" onmouseout="MouseOutMethod(this)">COMMENTS</a>
            <div style="clear: both;"></div>
</div>
```

Add following javascript functions and change the color as you need.

```
function MouseHoverMethod(x) {
     x.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
}

function MouseOutMethod(x) {
     x.style.backgroundColor = 'black';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is far to complicated. You are breaking rule #1 of programming: DRY - Don't repeat yourself.

Also there is no need to set the color with JavaScript, instead set a class to to selected item and use that to style it.

Example: (without the red arrow stuff, because without the style sheet it's difficult to see what you are doing there, and it probably could be replaced with some pure CSS, too):

```
<div class="software_section_selects_wrapper">
    <a onclick="displayTab(this, 'overview')">OVERVIEW</a>
    <a onclick="displayTab(this, 'specs')">SPECS</a>
    <a onclick="displayTab(this, 'comments')">COMMENTS</a>
    <div style="clear: both;"></div>
</div>

<div class="tabs">
    <div id="overview" class="software_overview">
    </div>
    <div id="specs" class="software_overview">
    </div>
    <div id="comments" class="software_overview">
    </div>
</div>
```

---

JS:

```
<script>
   function clearClass(elements) {
      for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
          elements[i].className = '';
      }
   }

   function displayTab(link, tabId) {
      var links = link.parentNode.getElementsByTagName('a');
      clearClass(links);
      link.className = 'active';

      var tab = document.getElementById(tabId);
      var tabs = tab.parentNode.getElementsByTagName('div');
      clearClass(tabs);
      tab.className = 'active';
   }
</script>
```

---

CSS:

```
.tabs > div {
    display: none;
}

.tabs > div.active {
    display: block;
}

.software_section_selects_wrapper > a {
    color: white;
    background-color: black;
}

.software_section_selects_wrapper > a.active {
    color: white;
    background-color: red;
}
```

Live: http://jsfiddle.net/d9ffnw46/1/

BTW, you should look into using a framework library such as jQuery. As a beginner it makes code such as this much simpler.

EDIT: Here's an example with jQuery: http://jsfiddle.net/d9ffnw46/2/